# How to modify the format when printing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, termcolor

My goal is to be able to change the default format when printing in Python.

With the following code, I can change color, bold and centering. I would also like to change the font size and even the font style but I don't know how.

```
from termcolor import colored
print(colored('Hello'.center(100), 'green', attrs=['bold']))
```

Answer (score 0):

To add color, you can also use :

```
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

print(f"{bcolors.WARNING}Warning: No active frommets remain. Continue?{bcolors.ENDC}")
```

or :

```
def colored(r, g, b, text):
    return "\033[38;2;{};{};{}m{} \033[38;2;255;255;255m".format(r, g, b, text)
  
text = 'Hello, World'
colored_text = colored(255, 0, 0, text)
print(colored_text)
#or
print(colored(255, 0, 0, 'Hello, World'))
```